# No WiFi on Mac Mini 7,1 for kubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, broadcom

I installed kubuntu on one of my hardrives to do some stuff with the internet  but I dont have wifi drivers. I am using a bluetooth pan to acesss the internet I am going to try these commands

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer

Comment: I forgot to mention its a late 2014 model

Comment: Are you quite certain you have a Broadcom device? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

As per the known issues section of the ubuntu 19.04 release notes (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes) it suggests that you reinstall the broadcom drivers using the command "sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source". I would suggest you purge the previous driver installs and use reccomended method from ubuntu. It worked for me on my mid 2012 macbook pro.